# Is there an extension for jQuery code-completion in Coda?

Tags: jquery, ide, code-completion, coda

Do you know if there is a plugin for Coda to do the kind of code completion below for jquery? As far as i know there is such extension for Visual Studio, hope there is a way to do that in Coda too, because i don't want to write `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... });` anymore.

Thanks,
Sinan.

*P.S. I'm aware of shorthands of document ready like `$(function() { ... });`but it's still long and it's not the only issue makes me look for a completion extension.*

[alt text http://www.dbvy.com/Picture.png](http://www.dbvy.com/Picture.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this web post which has a jQuery.mode that you can use for Coda:

[jQuery Syntax Mode](http://digitalsandbox.net/index.php/project/category/jquery%5Fsyntax%5Fmode/)

Comment: I didn't know this, i tried it just now. It is a good attempt but not what i dreamt of. It needs a way to go, most you use jquery syntax is in inline editing in html, php, or in template files and therefore you need to make some little hacks:(, but since there is no other mode available this will be the accepted answer. Thanks for posting.

Comment: If you read the post it sounds like most of the limitations are because of how Coda is programed not the mode.  Sounds like the next version of Coda should fix some of this.

Comment: Sorry for being lazy to not to read the whole post:) Hope coda will fix that soon. Thanks again. btw do you know if such mode exist for textmate?

Comment: You can check out a jQuery tmbundle from github http://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-tmbundle/tree/master 

blog post about it here:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/textmate-bundle-for-jquery

Comment: Only problem is that his bundle doesn't seem to support syntax coloring. Any workaround to have jQuery's autocompletion and Javascript's coloring?